# Creating an Attribute class that allows adjusting a base value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, attributes, set

I want to create an `Attribute` class so I can do stuff like:

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self, health=100, armor=0):
        self.health = Attribute(health)
        self.armor = Attribute(armor)
```

Now when I do

```
c1 = Creature()
c1.health += 10
```

It actually doesn't change the real value, but it keeps `health`'s *base* value at 100, while giving it an adjustment of +10.

Here's what I tried, but it works using `healt.get()` and `health.set()` which is not wanted:

```
class Attribute:
    def __init__(self, base=0, adjustments=None):
        self._base = base
        self._adjustments = adjustments or []

    def set(self, value):
        difference = value - self._base
        if difference:
            self._adjustments.append(difference)

    def get(self):
        return self._base + sum(self._adjustments)

c1 = Creature(50)
c1.health.set(60)  # Adds +10 adjustment
```

But I  want to be able to do this:

```
c1 = Creature(50)
c1.health = 60
# Or just:
c1.health += 10
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you want a combinations of [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and `__iadd__()`

Comment: @Alex's answer is right and the simplest one. But if you have to use classes for property, you can use Meta classes. That's how Django models work. eg `country = models.TextField(max_length=5, default='US').` You can see you can add additional meta information and abstract out the usual validations into another classes. You can now use the property like a normal property: `obj.country = 'ENG'.` When I am back to work, I will post sample code on how to do that.

Comment: This is very likely a bad idea. Pretending to be an integer but acting like something else entirely is extremely confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are four approaches that might meet your needs.

---

### Descriptors

[Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) allow you to provide direct attribute access while hiding the underlying implementation.

```
class AttributeDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.initialized = False
        self.base = 0
        self.adjustments = []

    def compute(self):
        return self.base + sum(self.adjustments)

    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        if not self.initialized:
            self.base = value
            self.initialized = True
            print("Attribute initialized to %s" % value)
        else:
            # Calculate delta
            delta = (value - self.compute())
            self.adjustments.append(delta)
            print("Adjustment added: %s" % delta)

    def __get__(self, inst, owner):
        return self.compute()

class Creature(object):
    health = AttributeDescriptor()
    armor  = AttributeDescriptor()

    def __init__(self, health=100, armor=0):
        self.health = health
        self.armor  = armor


c1 = Creature(50)
c1.health = 60      # Adds a +10 adjustment
print c1.health     # 60
c1.health += 10     # Add a +10 adjustment
print c1.health     # 70
#print c1.health.adjustments     # This won't work ('int' object has no attribute 'adjustments')
```

Output:

```
Attribute initialized to 50
Attribute initialized to 0
Adjustment added: 10
60
Adjustment added: 10
70
```

The problem with this approach is that you have no easy way to access the internals of the descriptor.  So in this case, you can't ever inspect the `adjustments` list.  You can, however, directly assign `c1.health = X` to it as if it were a normal attribute.

**Note:** As noted by Veedrac in the comments, these attributes are defined at the class level and *will be shared between all instances* of the `Creature` class.  For this reason alone it's not a solution whatsoever, but it wasn't a great solution in any case.

### Normal Tracker Objects

You can use a class that implements the "[augmented assignment](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/)" magic methods `__iadd__()` and `__isub__()`

```
class AttributeObject(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        self.base = base
        self.adjustments = []
        print("Attribute initialized to %s" % base)

    def __compute(self):
        return self.base + sum(self.adjustments)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.__compute()

    def __iadd__(self, delta):
        print("Adjustment added: %s" % delta)
        self.adjustments.append(delta)
        return self

    def __isub__(self, delta):
        print("Adjustment added: %s" % -delta)
        self.adjustments.append(-delta)
        return self

class Creature(object):
    def __init__(self, health=100, armor=0):
        self.health = AttributeObject(health)
        self.armor =  AttributeObject(armor)


c1 = Creature(50)
#c1.health = 60         # Can't do this, because it will override the AttributeObject
print int(c1.health)    # 60
c1.health += 10         # Add a +10 adjustment
print int(c1.health)    # 70
print c1.health.adjustments  # [10]
```

Output:

```
Attribute initialized to 50
Attribute initialized to 0
50
Adjustment added: 10
60
[10]
```

The problem with this approach is that you can't directly assign to the attribute without overriding it.  In other words, `c1.health = X` will override the value of the `health` attribute to be equal to X -- you lose whatever was there previously.

But with this approach, you *can* access the `adjustments` list:  `print c1.health.adjustments`

Note that `c1.health` is an instance of `AdjustmentTracker`, not a numeric type like you may expect (try `print c1.health`).  You have a number of ways to access/extract the numeric value, in the example I use the `int(c1.health)` type conversion (possible since I implemented `__int__`).

### Descriptor + Tracker Object

Using a combination of the two above methods, you can use all of the syntax you listed.

```
class AttributeDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        getattr(inst, self.attr).update(value)

    def __get__(self, inst, owner):
        return getattr(inst, self.attr).compute()


class AdjustmentTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        print("Attribute initialized to %s" % base)
        self.base = base
        self.adjustments = []

    def compute(self):
        return self.base + sum(self.adjustments)

    def update(self, value):
        delta = (value - self.compute())
        print("Adjustment added: %s" % delta)
        self.adjustments.append(delta)


class Creature(object):
    health = AttributeDescriptor('_health')
    armor  = AttributeDescriptor('_armor')

    def __init__(self, health=100, armor=0):
        self._health = AdjustmentTracker(health)
        self._armor =  AdjustmentTracker(armor)


c1 = Creature(50)
c1.health = 60      # Adds a +10 adjustment
print c1.health     # 60
c1.health += 10     # Add a +10 adjustment
print c1.health     # 70
print c1._health.adjustments     # [10, 10]
```

Output:

```
Attribute initialized to 50
Attribute initialized to 0
Adjustment added: 10
60
Adjustment added: 10
70
[10, 10]
```

Here, the descriptors aren't keeping track of the base and adjustment list themselves, rather you're using them as a proxy to interface with `AdjustmentTracker` obejcts.  With this you can do both direct assignment (e.g. `c1.health = 60`) *and* access the underlying initial base / adjustments (e.g. `c1._health.adjustments`).

### Properties + Tracker Objects

Just as in the previous example, we use `AdjustmentTracker` objects to hold the state of the attributes.  But in this example, instead of using an explicit descriptors, you can use [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to shield the attribute.

```
class AdjustmentTracker(object):
    def __init__(self, base):
        print("Attribute initialized to %s" % base)
        self.base = base
        self.adjustments = []

    def compute(self):
        return self.base + sum(self.adjustments)

    def update(self, value):
        delta = (value - self.compute())
        print("Adjustment added: %s" % delta)
        self.adjustments.append(delta)


class Creature(object):
    @property
    def health(self):         return self._health.compute()
    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):  self._health.update(value)

    @property
    def armor(self):          return self._armor.compute()
    @armor.setter
    def armor(self, value):   self._armor.update(value)

    def __init__(self, health=100, armor=0):
        self._health = AdjustmentTracker(health)
        self._armor =  AdjustmentTracker(armor)


c1 = Creature(50)
c1.health = 60      # Adds a +10 adjustment
print c1.health     # 60
c1.health += 10     # Add a +10 adjustment
print c1.health     # 70
print c1._health.adjustments     # [10, 10]
```

Output:

```
Attribute initialized to 50
Attribute initialized to 0
Adjustment added: 10
60
Adjustment added: 10
70
[10, 10]
```

This example is basically the same as the previous one, just less lines of code since it makes use of properties, and functions exactly the same.

Comment: The first example stores the value at class-level, so all `Creature`s share the same health and armor.

Comment: @Veedrac, you're right -- let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: @Veedrac, I "fixed" it -- what an ugly solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll memory leak.

Comment: It shouldn't keep `Creature` elements alive since it's just a hash, but it will never free information about collected instances.  I rolled back the edit and noted your concern.  If I can figure out a nice way to handle this I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

Check out properties
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

In the example below a property is being used as a decorator.

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self, health):
        self._base_health = health
        self._modifications = []
    @property
    def health(self):
        return self._base_health + sum(self._modifications)
    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self._modifications.append(value - self._base_health - sum(self._modifications))
```

Every time the health attribute is retrieved the getter function (the function marked with the `property` decorator) is called. Similarly when the health attribute is set the setter function (the function marked with the `health.setter` decorator) is called.

```
c1 = Creature(50)
c1.health = 60
c1.health += 10
print(c1.health)
c1.health = 40
print(c1.health)
```

outputs

```
70
40
```